# Nothing happens when item of navigation bar clicked

Tags: android, navigationview

I have used google's sample navigation activity. In that I have modified the navigation bar items. I want to start a new activity when an item is clicked.

I have add onNavigationItemClicked event as well, still when I click on the item nothing happens.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private TextView name, email;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_my_printers:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyPrintersActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Not yet Implemented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    name = headerView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);

    name.setText(SessionClass.getUserInSession().getName());
    email.setText(SessionClass.getUserInSession().getEmail());

    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_my_printers, R.id.nav_settings)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Calls `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` internally to connect destinations to menu items. This overrides the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` view you've set.

Navigation supports `<activity>` destinations, allowing you to use the default `setupWithNavController` functionality out of the box. You'd add an activity destination to your graph that uses the same id as your menu item:

```
<activity
  android:id="@+id/nav_my_printers"
  android:name=".MyPrintersActivity"/>
```

Then the default `setupWithNavController` will call `startActivity` for you.